# Is there any way (cheats included) to botch the Foundation quest in The Outer Worlds, without actually killing anyone?

Tags: cheats, the-outer-worlds

After many quests where I was able to tell someone I'll do something for them, and then working against them behind their back, like

> agreeing to send tracking signal from computer in the orbital lab, and then sending corrupted one, or toothpaste war alternatives, and more

I came to expect that I will always be allowed to accept a job and then ignore it or intentionally go against it. Sadly, with the [Foundation](https://theouterworlds.fandom.com/wiki/Foundation) quest it is not so easy. I was told that I need to go and kill

> everyone in the starting city, Edgewater

and it was implied that if I'll refuse I will have to fight my way out of the building I was in, killing important NPCs from The Board, undoubtedly loosing reputation and probably being effectively locked out of the Byzantium. I wasn't prepared to do that yet, so I agreed, as reluctantly as dialog options allowed me to.

Turns out, all my companions now believe I am going to do this. I have no option to tell them I lied. I tried to look for a guide on turning this quest against The Board, and it turns out this quest does not have branches, game expect you to only agree if you really agree... What a letdown! Too bad I went several hours adventuring before I figured that out, so loading old save and not talking with quest giver is something I do not want to do.

Is there any cheat, save editor, glitch, or anything that would mark this quest as botched, make my companions stop pestering me about it, but wouldn't give me 100% negative reputation with The Board and Byzantium? An equivalent to just telling everyone *"I lied to get us out of there, now we forget about it"* that game writers team forgot to put there? I wasn't able to play for quite a few days, because this situation really cut on my enjoyment.

Comment: From that wiki page you shared: `Accepting the quest does not mean the player has to complete it.` Is this not an option for you?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas but my companions will ask me about it and may leave, and I don't want that.

Comment: Right, that's the tradeoff. You'll need to pass some checks to keep your companions as, well, companions.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes. When I shouldn't have to do it if the game was consistent and allowed me to oppose quest instead of going with it, like it trained me to expect.